# Nitrogen (Erlang web framework) file upload and validators on other form elements

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

I am using [Nitrogen](http://nitrogenproject.com/). And I have an `#upload` element together with a `#textarea` element. When a user presses the button to upload the file the `#textarea` also gets posted and I can receive it with `wf:q/1` in the `finish_upload_even/4` function. This is all good but I want to wire a `#validator` to the `#textarea` and cannot find the `TriggerId` to use. Am I misunderstanding something or is this functionality not obvious? Maybe even impossible as of now?

Comment: Show us your Nitrogen source code please so that we show you where to position the validator.

Comment: we need the source, you could be doing something perhaps the wrong way.